# Django комментарий на комментарий

Tags: django

Задача такая: Реализовать возможность ответить на комментарий пользователя. Грубо говоря оставить комментарий на комментарий.

Имеется Djamgo 2.2, Python 3.7

**models.py**

```
***
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post_comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Комментарий')
    content = models.TextField('Комментарий')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comment_author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор'))
***
```

Я не могу понять что нужно добавить в модель что бы получить возможность комментировать комментарии. Точнее так - я думаю что нужно добавить модели ссылку на саму себя, но не уверен.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Унаследовать Comment и Post от общего корня и сделать ForeignKey на него.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот и я так думаю, но не хотелось бы плодить модели... Или я опять ни чего не понял...

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в модель родителя комментария. С помощью js передавать id . И немного подправить vies

```
 parent = models.ForeignKey(
            'self', verbose_name="Родитель", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True
        )
```

А вообще много чего еще надо сделать, не знаю можно ли кидать ссылки на видео, но вот пример с объяснением, там в принципе все понятно объясняет https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HffHoacEUxU
если что это не мои и это не рекламы, просто описывать много чего надо